# "New" operator works in extern "C"

Tags: c#, c++, dll, extern

Im using a C++ DLL for my C# project, DLL has a class inside which is created  and destroyed by outer functions such as:

```
 class myClass
 {
   int N;
   public:
        //some elements and some functions

        myClass(int n)
        {
            N=n;
        }
 };

 __declspec(dllexport) myClass * builderF(int n)
 {

      return new myClass(n);

 }

 __declspec(dllexport) void destroyerF(myClass * c)
 {

      delete c;

 }
```

and these are in extern "C" {} body.

How does the compiler let me use C++ features is "C" space? Isnt it for only C code? This is tested and works(Ive started making an opencl wrapper for C#). I was using only pure C codes before.

Comment: May be helpful: [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern “C”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)

Comment: So linking is completely different than compiling? So it just compiles as a C++ code.

Comment: This not only compiles, but really works? I mean, `destroyerF` function? o.O

Comment: Yes, Im creating with an int parameter lets say "44" then reading it from C# then deleting the class by a dll-call.

Comment: I suppose, it's `destroyerF( myClass * c)` then...

Comment: Yes. I did not copy-paste, I wrote by hand and made error :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`extern "C"` doesn't change the compiler into a C compiler.  It
only says that any functions (or pointers to functions) will use
the C conventions in their interface.  So you can still do
anything you could do in C++ in the functions; it's only things
like name mangling and calling conventions which will be
affected.

Comment: Okay, this is more cleaner now. Thank you. Accepting in minutes. Must every compiler give exactly same behaviour?

Comment: Following up on James' answer, the only thing you cannot do in an `extern "C"` block is overload functions; overloading is managed via name mangling, which as James addresses, isn't there within this block.

Comment: +1: Note that some compilers can be switched in to C-mode using directives, but this is not how.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik It depends on what you mean by the same behavior.  Every compiler is required to parse and compile the code as C++ (with certain restrictions: as mah says, you can't overload functions).  What the C calling conventions are depends on the compiler, and which C compiler it is targeting (normally, the C ABI of the system, if it has one).

Comment: @JohnDibling Naming the file `.c`, instead of `.cpp`, `.cxx`, `.cc` or `.C` is normally sufficient.

Comment: @James Kanze Okay, I got it. Function parameter passing is always C++ style as I suspect.

Comment: Obviously.  But that won't work when C and C++ is mixed in the same file.  Not saying such a mixture should exist, just adding information.

Comment: @JohnDibling Ah.  You were talking about `#pragma`, or some such.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yup.  I personally have never used them, but I know they exist.